# Google SignIn: catch deny from grantOfflineAccess method (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-signin

I'm implementing Google Sign In, but instead of the signIn() method I need to use grantOfflineAccess() on the client side. Everything works great, except that I'm not finding a way to catch when the user deny the permission or close the popup. I doesn't give any response or exception. I just get some response when the user gives permission.
The weird thing is that this is really easy to achieve using he signIn() method...
Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?